# Fourier Transforms and Series for the NON mathematically inclined.

Tags: fourier-transform, fourier-series

This would most likely be the opposite of this question ( [Mathematically inclined Signal and Systems/Signal Processing book?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9110/mathematically-inclined-signal-and-systems-signal-processing-book?newreg=8946fadf496b4c42ac1eaa19a8aff997) ) I figured I'd ask here if there are any good books that while, necessarily, focus on the math are more oriented to what these concepts can DO instead of the mathematics behind it, so I guess more how it changes the graphing or the function etc instead of the functions behind them.

Comment: Have you looked at the materials suggested in [this answer](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/1339/235)?

Answer (score 4):

The book "Blip, Ping & Buzz", by M. Denny (2007, John Hopkins University Press), explains signal processing, as used in sonar and radar, at the level of a supermarket science magazine.  Some algebra required.  More on the use of Fourier analysis than any theory.

Comment: That one wasn't on my radar.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

Title: "The World According to Wavelets"
Author: Barber Burke Hubbard
Publisher:  A K Peters

This book covers Fourier series, Fourier transforms and lots of related concepts as an introduction to another topic you may find interesting, wavelet analysis.

The book is in two parts.  Part one is non-technical.  Part includes some math.  The book also discusses the history and application of these important tools.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to understand digital signal processing concepts, i would suggest that you make peace with the math before going forward. You might find one or two books that explain things with some analogies and sort of in the air without dealing with the math, but eventually you need to know it. Math is not as bad as it seems.

Comment: It's not that I want to avoid the math entirely just that there are two ways to explain a concept at first; just the math give integrals or summations or give graphs etc, the former I, at least, don't go oh ya duh.